# Force and lock orientation at runtime with phonegap / cordova v3.x on iOS

Tags: objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Once again I'm hoping someone with right set of skills will help me with my problem. Previously asked question wasn't answered so now targeting more tags. My problem is.. well title says it all :) Thank you in advance

Comment: Refer - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/LsztccN3RpA

Comment: Thanks, but my android app works well and I have no problems with it, it's iOS that I'm struggling with... I use this com.phonegap.plugins.OrientationLock plugin which requires 0 input and works out of the box but only with android...

Comment: Set your question on the description not in Title please